# How to restore memos on Samsung S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean, bugs

I have used the memo app which came with Android (the one with the big "T" logo) successfully for years. Today it suddenly lost all my memos without warning. Is this a known bug? Is there some way to restore the memos? Where are they normally stored?

I haven't synced with Google for a while (it seems authentication changed after upgrading to 4.1.2), so that option is not available.

I haven't installed any new apps since upgrading to 4.1.2 (and the Memo app *did* work successfully for a while after upgrading). I *have* disabled some apps which I have never used (at least not directly):

- ChatON
- Clock (digital, funky and modern)
- com.google.android.voicese... (I can't seem to display the rest of the name)
- Dual Clock (analogue and digital)
- Exchange Services
- Face Unlock
- Game Hub
- Google Play Music
- Group Cast
- Kobo
- PressReader
- Readers Hub
- SNS
- Street View
- Talk
- TalkBack
- Voice command
- Yahoo! Finance
- Yahoo! News
- Zinio

Comment: Do you mean Samsung's app **S Memo**?

Comment: Did it crash, or did just disappear? Did you do anything before it got lost, like install an app?